# "Proxy-Authorization" is removed at the destination server

Tags: node.js, request

i use `request` module to consume web services. the web services expect `Proxy-Authorization` field in the header.

i send this value, but in the destination server, `Proxy-Authorization` is gone.

please help.

Comment: Proxy-Authorization is a single hop header I guess. One of the proxies in path to the destination sever must have consumed it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got some helps from my colleage, here is the way to work-around.
just override proxyHeaderExclusiveList

```
const proxyHeaderExclusiveList = [];
  proxyHeaderExclusiveList.concat = function newConcat() {
    return this;
  };
  const options = {
    url: SOME_URL,
    headers: SOME_HEADERS,
    proxyHeaderExclusiveList: proxyHeaderExclusiveList
  };
```